# How to combine conditional style class and non conditional under one tag?

Tags: vue.js

Should I use both `class` and `:class` at the same time under one tag or there's another way to do this?

```
  <span 
      @click="toggleDetails()" 
      class="btn btn-xs"
      :class="[isActive ? 'btn-warning' : 'btn-info']">details</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should, and It's totally fine (reccomended in docs)

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax